# Object is null in method, but not in the class

Tags: java, null

I am creating a game engine, but I have run into an error.

I have a `static` `Object` representing a directional light source which I initialize at the beginning of my class. But when I try to use the method which sets my uniforms they always trigger my null test and are `null`.

```
public class PhongShader extends Shader {

    private static final PhongShader instance = new PhongShader();

    public static PhongShader getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    private static Vector3f ambientLight = new Vector3f(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f);
    private static DirectionalLight light1 = new DirectionalLight(new BaseLight(new Vector3f(1, 1, 1), 0), new Vector3f(0, 0, 0));

    public PhongShader() {
        super();

        addVertexShader(ResourceLoader.loadShader("phongVertex.vs"));
        addFragmentShader(ResourceLoader.loadShader("phongFragment.fs"));
        compileShader();

        addUniform("transform");
        addUniform("transformProjected");
        addUniform("sampler");
        addUniform("baseColor");
        addUniform("ambientLight");

        addUniform("directionalLight.base.color");
        addUniform("directionalLight.base.intensity");
        addUniform("directionalLight.direction");
    }

    public void updateUniforms(Matrix4f worldMatrix, Matrix4f projectedMatrix, Material material) {
        if (material.getTexture() != null) {
            material.getTexture().bind();
        }
        setUniform("transform", worldMatrix);
        setUniform("transformProjected", projectedMatrix);
        setUniformi("sampler", 0);
        setUniform("baseColor", material.getColor());

        setUniform("ambientLight", PhongShader.ambientLight);
        setUniform("directionalLight", getDirectionalLight());
    }

    public static void setAmbientLight(Vector3f ambientLight) {
        PhongShader.ambientLight = ambientLight;
    }

    public static void setDirectionalLight(DirectionalLight directionalLight) {
        PhongShader.light1 = directionalLight;
    }

    public static DirectionalLight getDirectionalLight() {
        return light1;
    }

    public void setUniform(String uniformName, BaseLight baseLight) {
        if (baseLight.equals(null)) {
            setUniform(uniformName + ".color", baseLight.getColor());           
            setUniformf(uniformName + ".intensity", baseLight.getIntensity());
        }
        System.out.println("baseLight is null, shader can not conitnue!");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    public void setUniform(String uniformName, DirectionalLight directionalLight) {
        if (directionalLight.equals(null)) {
            setUniform(uniformName + ".base", directionalLight.getBase());
            setUniform(uniformName + ".direction", directionalLight.getDirection());
        }
        System.out.println('\n' + "directionalLight is null, shader can not continue!");
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

If I run this with the method `setUniform` taking a `DirectionalLight` the method returns saying that the directional light is `null`. I have tried putting tests around the class to see when `DirectionalLight` goes `null` and it doesn't.

```
setUniform("directionalLight", getDirectionalLight());
```

but it is reported after this method gets executed.

Comment: Which line gives to you the error?

Comment: your setUniform methods don't make any sense: they either calls the other setUniform method or exit the program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, nothing will `.equals(null)`. Second, it appears your logic is inverted. I think you wanted something like

```
public void setUniform(String uniformName, DirectionalLight directionalLight) {
    if (directionalLight != null) {
        setUniform(uniformName + ".base", directionalLight.getBase());
        setUniform(uniformName + ".direction", directionalLight.getDirection());
    } else {
        System.out.println("\ndirectionalLight is null, shader can not continue!");
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

And similarly with your other `setUniform` method

```
public void setUniform(String uniformName, BaseLight baseLight) {
    if (baseLight != null) {
        setUniform(uniformName + ".color", baseLight.getColor());           
        setUniformf(uniformName + ".intensity", baseLight.getIntensity());
    } else {
        System.out.println("baseLight is null, shader can not conitnue!");
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: If I do your test using the != operator instead of my .equals(null) the setUniform with DirectionalLight does not error with a null value. But the setUniform with BaseLight returns a null value.

Comment: @nicholasl99 **Nothing** is ***ever*** `.equals(null)` in Java. And, if it were, then calling `baseLight.getColor()` would be a `NullPointerException`. Actually, calling `baseLight.equals` would be a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: The reason why is that the object that the `equals()` method is called on cannot itself be null without a NullPointerException being thrown.